# End Point not found in custom WCF service with share point 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, web-services, wcf, isapi

I am creating a custom Wcf service in sharepoint 2013

my code as  below.

**objectiveIntegration.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost
    Language="C#"
    Debug="true"
    Service="Technologies.Test.ObjectiveIntegration.Services.ObjectievIntegrationService, Technologies.Test.ObjectiveIntegration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7d4eb69574ae9195"
    CodeBehind="ObjectievIntegrationService.svc.cs"
    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory,Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

**Code Behind :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Technologies.Test.ObjectiveIntegration.ISAPI.Technologies.Test.ObjectiveIntegration
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IObjectIntegrationService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                   UriTemplate = "ObjectiveIntegrationGetList/{value}",
                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetUserPassedString(string value);


        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                   UriTemplate = "ObjectiveIntegrationUploadDoc/{webID}/{siteID}/{libraryID}/{itemID}",
                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        bool DownloadDocument(string webID, string siteID, string libraryID, string itemID);

    }

}
```

**Calling service Contract from below**

```
using Technologies.Test.ObjectiveIntegration.ISAPI.Technologies.Test.ObjectiveIntegration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace Technologies.Test.ObjectiveIntegration.Services
{



    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

    public class ObjectievIntegrationService : IObjectIntegrationService
    {
        public string GetUserPassedString(string value)
        {
            return value;
        }

        public bool DownloadDocument(string webID, string siteID, string libraryID, string itemID)
        {
            bool isDocumentDownload = false;
            try
            {
                // Get the SharePoint site collection from the given siteID.
                using (SPSite objSite = new SPSite(Guid.Parse(siteID)))
                {
                    if (objSite == null)
                    {
                        // To Do Message
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        using (SPWeb objWeb = objSite.AllWebs[Guid.Parse(webID)])
                        {
                            if (objWeb == null)
                            {
                                // To Do Message
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Get the Document library from the selected Web from specific Site.
                                SPList objList = objWeb.Lists[Guid.Parse(libraryID)];
                                if (objList == null)
                                {
                                    // To Do Message
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // Get listItem from the selected Document library from specific web in specific site.
                                    SPListItem objListItem = objList.Items[Guid.Parse(itemID)];
                                    if (objListItem == null)
                                    {
                                        // To Do Message
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        // Check List Item is file or folder.
                                        if (objListItem.File == null)
                                        {
                                            // To Do Message
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            // To Do Code for upload
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return isDocumentDownload;
        }


    }

}
```

**I have added "svc" refrence in csproject**.

I have share point ISAPI mapped folder in solution.

**Now when i calling from the _ti_bin folder service give me message that "End point not found".**
**(http://Test11/sites/DemoTemplate/_vti_bin/Technologies.Test.ObjectiveIntegration/ObjectiveIntegrationServices.svc)**

Please any one help me out.

Answer (score -1):

Check the assembly name of your project from project properties and make sure same is used in the svc file.

You may also try to use `$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$` so that it get automatically resolved. Example:

```
<%@ ServiceHost
    Language="C#"
    Debug="true"
    Service="Technologies.Test.ObjectiveIntegration.Services.ObjectievIntegrationService, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
    CodeBehind="ObjectievIntegrationService.svc.cs"
    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory,Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```